# How to Select by LINQ into anonymous type in F#

Tags: .net, linq, f#

I have this code snippet, which creates an array of anonymously typed elements with properties Name and FirstLetter:

```
string[] arr = { "Dennis", "Leo", "Paul" };

var myRes = arr.Select(a => new { Name = a, FirstLetter = a[0] });
```

I would like to do the same in F#. I tried:

```
let names = [| "Dennis"; "Leo"; "Paul" |]

let myRes = names.Select(fun a -> {Name = a; FirstLetter = a[0]} )
```

But this doesn't compile. It says:

*The record label 'Name' is not defined.*

How can I get this line to work in F#?

Comment: No such luck yet: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5673015-support-c-like-anonymous-types-in-f (F# supports neither creating Anonymous Types or Anonymous Records)

Comment: You can use tuples which are anonymous but do not have labels, or you can define record type before selecting values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in comments, F# doesn't support anonymous type. So if you want to project your sequence into another sequence, create a record, which is essentially a tuple with named fields.

```
type p = { 
  Name:string;
  FirstLetter: char 
}

let names = [| "Dennis"; "Leo"; "Paul" |]
let myRes = names.Select(fun a -> {Name = a; FirstLetter = a.[0]} )
```

Comment: The request to add anonymous types in F# has been getting a bit of traction lately. https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/207

Comment: This answer was right at the time the question was originally asked but see my new answer based on the new Anonymous Records feature in F# 4.6.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55605117/83658

Answer (score 4):

Your initial attempts would work more intuitively as of F# 4.6. Testing a similar example using **.NET Core SDK 3.0.100-preview4** I was able to prove this out using the new [Anonymous Record](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/207) feature.

```
let names = [| "Dennis"; "Leo"; "Paul" |]

let myRes = names.Select(fun a -> {| Name = a; FirstLetter = a.[0] |})
```

Notice the use of the `|` character on the insides of the curly braces. This is what now distinguishes regular records from anonymous records in F#. Also notice that when accessing the first character of a string in F# that the `.` [method accessor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/) must be used to access the indexer just like when accessing other methods.